# Does Staff of Provocation allow enemy attack himself?

Tags: dnd-4e, attack

Suppose two players are fighting, and one of them has the Staff of Provocation (PHB2):

> Power (Daily ✦Charm):Free Action.
>
> Trigger: You hit an enemy with an attack power using this staff.
>
> Effect: One creature of your choice makes a melee basic attack against that enemy as a free action. The attacking creature gains a bonus to the attack roll and the damage roll equal to your Intelligence modifier.

Can the player use this power on his opponent, and choose the opponent makes the attack against himself? Can he use this on his opponent, then choose *himself* to make the MBA against his opponent?

Comment: What happened to the second question? I thought the point was to give HIMSELF another MBA against the other player? Why would he use the power to attack himself?

Comment: His second question, as written, was to say player 1 targets himself to attack player 1. Maybe there was a typo there. @Kai, did you mean to say choosing yourself to player 2 in your second question? If so, please edit your question to clarify. :)

Comment: 1 - enemy attack himself and 2 - recieve MBA against enemy

Comment: Jonathan, not to quibble but the wording of the power and the wording of your re-edit are what I was trying to clarify with my previous edit. The way the power works, if you "use it on someone" (It only has one possible target for the power itself) that is the creature who gets the attack. The attack that is generated can then only target the initial defender against the original (triggering) attack power.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Can you make an enemy attack themselves?

Yes, you can. "One creature of your choice" means *any* creature, unless the power itself provides a limitation on that.

Some powers, such as the Sorcerer's *Lightning Strike*, have wording like this: *"An enemy of your choice other than the target ...*" - that limitation isn't made here, so the creature chosen can be the same creature you hit with the attack.

#### Can you target your enemy and choose yourself to make the attack?

Yes. There's no limitation preventing you from being the attacker.

Comment: Yep, I ask abt 1st and 3th question. Thx for editing and answer.